# Should WebApplicationFactory<> be disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit.net

I  have an `Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api` application.

I have Integration tests made with `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory). I Inject it in the xUnit test class with  `IClassFixture<WebAdminTestApplicationFactory<Program>>`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#cascade-dispose-calls):

> If your class owns a field or property, and its type implements
> IDisposable, the containing class itself should also implement
> IDisposable. A class that instantiates an IDisposable implementation
> and storing it as an instance member, is also responsible for its
> cleanup.

Then why MSDN examples for Integration tests don't dispose `WebApplicationFactory` which they have as a field?

Shouldn't `WebApplicationFactory` be disposed? Because it does implement IDisposable.

Comment: Given that `WebApplicationFactory<T>.Dispose` is a non-trivial method (i.e. it _does_ dispose stuff) I think that _you should_ call `.Dispose` or use a `using` statement (or whatever the equivalent is for `IAsyncDisposable`) in your `IClassFixture` - though I'm unsure if xUnit supports `IAsyncDisposable` yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your test class doesn't **own** `WebApplicationFactory<Program>`: it's injected by xUnit, which creates and calls `Dispose` on it for you.

See [Shared Context between Tests: Class Fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context):

> When using a class fixture, xUnit.net will ensure that the fixture instance will be created before any of the tests have run, and once all the tests have finished, it will clean up the fixture object by calling `Dispose`, if present.